# Как сделать индикатор запуска приложения?

Tags: java, android

При запуске приложения происходит загрузка настроек и предрасчет.

Как сделать чтобы в это время на пустом экране был какой-то индикатор, что идет запуск, чтобы пользователь не волновался, что "прога висит"?

Comment: Вы же можете отследить, когда закончится "загрузка настроек и предрасчет"? Добавьте активити, который появляется при запуске приложения и показывается, пока нужно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В случае если вы делаете какие-то запросы в сеть, просто долгие (но асинхронные) операции при запуске - то просто отобразите диалог-прогресс или что-то подобное. Если же вы имеете в виду эффект "белого экрана" при запуске приложения, во время которого происходят всякие инициализации всякого, то вот вам кошерное решение через стили.

1. Создаём минимум два стиля - один основной стиль приложения, второй - для заставки. Во втором укажите картинку из ресурсов в качестве фона для окна через атрибут `android:windowBackground`. Также можно и ещё и `android:colorPrimaryDark` указать.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark" tools:ignore="NewApi">@color/splashBackground</item>
</style>
```

2. В манифесте укажите основой стиль приложения в теге `application`, а для основной активити укажите второй стиль:

```
<application
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

3. В `onCreate` методе главной активити смените стиль как только начнётся непосредственное выполнение вашего кода в этом методе, т.е. сразу после `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
```

Таким образом система, при старте вашего приложения, отобразит и будет отображать картинку вами указанную на экране до тех пор пока внутренние инициализации всякого будут выполняться (например инициализация `FCM`, `Realm` etc в `onCreate` класса `Application` может на некоторых девайсах занимать несколько секунд, что приводит к превращению приложения в "фонарик" на всё это время)

Comment: Очень интересно! А можно ли отображать не картинку а разметку?

Comment: Да, было бы интересно попробовать другую разметку. Это можно?

Comment: @kaaa, нет, разметку не получится. Она загружается методом `setContentView`, а он будет вызван только после всех долгих внутренних инициализаций.

Comment: Ну в любом случае можно сделать разметку, ее заскринить вот тебе и картинка