# Польза переопределения Application

Tags: android

Допустим, в моем приложении 30 активностей. Я помечаю `android.action.LAUNCHER` ту, что должна запускаться из лончера. Но этот процесс долгий! Висит белый экран (не говорите про сплэш, это чисто философский вопрос). Я думаю что виноват в этом класс `Application`, который, наверное, ищет лаунчерную активность и ее запускает. Но зачем нам лишняя загрузка? Мы же можем создать свой класс, унаследованный от `Application` и в методе `onCrrate` не вызывать `super.onCreate()` а оставить просто код для перехода в нужную активность (стартовую) через `Intent`. Есть ли в этом толк? Ведь мы знаем какую активность запускать, не проще ли это сделать в java? Зачем эти пометки в манифесте?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На самом деле в классе Application неизвестно какую активити надо запускать. Там нет такой информации. `Application` - это единая точка входа для приложения и код в ней будет исполнен в т.ч. при вызовах ресиверов, запусков других активити при старте их по другим (не main) интентам запусков актвиити разных etc. Никакого поиска активити для запуска в манифесте не происходит.

Используете этот класс для первичной инициализации всякого. Например разных либ типа Realm, Dagger etc. Также невозможно запускать приложения с 65K+ методами на ОС<5 без переопределения этого класса (с расширением от MultidexApplication из спец-либы).

Кошерный способ избегания белого экрана при запуске - использование стилей. В нём надо прописать фоновое нетяжёлое изображение и именно оно будет показано вместо белого экрана при запуске. Вот тут подробно описано: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/658598/17609

Comment: Погодите, но кто же тогда запускает лончерную активность?

Comment: @Flippy, Intent всплывает в ОС, ОС смотрит есть ли кто-то для реакции на него, находит ваше приложение и запускает его. Но программа обязательно запускается через единую точку входа, класс Application. Как-то так.

Comment: А, сама ОС. Ну что ж, спасибо за информацию